# How to avoid export org-mode header title

Tags: export, org-mode, heading

I am translating a quite flat document (only has a title). I am using org-mode and I am creating a level 2 heading for each page to easily find the content when I am reviewing the translation which makes the process easier.

I wonder if there is a way to export the full document to PDF/HTML and not include the level 2 headings title but indeed include the full content. I need to ingore only heading's title.

Thanks.

Herewith an example:

```
* The document

** DONE Pag 1

bla bla...

** TODO Pag 2

...more bla bla...
```

Desired output:

```
* The document

bla bla...

(new page)

...more bla bla...
```